# compare 2 xml data and get difference in another xml in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, compare

I need to compare 2 xml files and write the difference(newly added rows) in third xml file.
The xml files has the result of a query. I found many third party tools but those are not specific for this condition. Any suggestions will he helpful.

```
xml1

<root>
<rdm>
<Model> aa</model>
</rdm>
<rdm>
<Model> bb </Model>
</rdm>
</root>

xml2

<root>
<rdm>
<Model> aa</model>
</rdm>
<rdm>
<Model> bb </Model>
</rdm>
<rdm>
<Model>cc</Model>
</rdm>
</root>

 The xml3 should look like 
<root>
<rdm>
<Model>cc</Model>
</rdm>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load your xml into two datasets, merge them and consider the new elements as the difference between them.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984388(v=vs.71).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30102/Comparing-DataSets-using-LINQ

Comment: GetChanges() does not return newly added rows. It is returning the original data in 1st dataset. and merge has duplicates in it which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own comparer by converting your XML files to objects using XmlDocument or XDocument. You can then compare two objects using `IEquatable.Equals()`. See this answer [C# XML Diffing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820209/c-sharp-xml-diffing-algorithm/28823131#28823131)