# Amadeus Airport Autocomplete using API on C#

Tags: c#, amadeus

im developing an app on C# and im using amadeus library for C#.
Im trying to get the AirportAutocomplete response that looks like this:

`[
  {
    "value": "MAD",
    "label": "Adolfo Suárez Madrid–Barajas Airport [MAD]"
  }
]`

Since the response its within brackets its not only an AiportAutocompleteResponse class its more like an array or list of AirportAutocompleteResponse class. If there where more matches to the search i will have a response like [this example](https://sandbox.amadeus.com/travel-innovation-sandbox/apis/get/airports/autocomplete).

The AirportAutocompleteResponse class:

```
public partial class AirportAutocompleteResponse :  IEquatable<AirportAutocompleteResponse>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AirportAutocompleteResponse" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public AirportAutocompleteResponse()
    {

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// The 3 letter IATA location code of the given city or airport. You can use this as an input parameter for a flight low-fare or inspiration search.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The 3 letter IATA location code of the given city or airport. You can use this as an input parameter for a flight low-fare or inspiration search.</value>
    [DataMember(Name="value", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string Value { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// The name of this airport, in UTF-8 format, prefixed with the name of the city if it is not already incorporated in the name of the airport, and appended with the location's IATA code (as in value), enclosed in square brackets.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The name of this airport, in UTF-8 format, prefixed with the name of the city if it is not already incorporated in the name of the airport, and appended with the location's IATA code (as in value), enclosed in square brackets.</value>
    [DataMember(Name="label", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
    public string Label { get; set; }



    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the string presentation of the object
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>String presentation of the object</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("class AirportAutocompleteResponse {\n");
        sb.Append("  Value: ").Append(Value).Append("\n");
        sb.Append("  Label: ").Append(Label).Append("\n");

        sb.Append("}\n");
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the JSON string presentation of the object
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>JSON string presentation of the object</returns>
    public string ToJson()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if objects are equal
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">Object to be compared</param>
    /// <returns>Boolean</returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        // credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10454552/677735
        return this.Equals(obj as AirportAutocompleteResponse);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if AirportAutocompleteResponse instances are equal
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">Instance of AirportAutocompleteResponse to be compared</param>
    /// <returns>Boolean</returns>
    public bool Equals(AirportAutocompleteResponse other)
    {
        // credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10454552/677735
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return 
            (
                this.Value == other.Value ||
                this.Value != null &&
                this.Value.Equals(other.Value)
            ) && 
            (
                this.Label == other.Label ||
                this.Label != null &&
                this.Label.Equals(other.Label)
            );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the hash code
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Hash code</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/677735
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 41;
            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)

            if (this.Value != null)
                hash = hash * 59 + this.Value.GetHashCode();

            if (this.Label != null)
                hash = hash * 59 + this.Label.GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }
    }

}
```

And the function im using to call the API:

```
public AirportAutocompleteResponse AirportAutocomplete (string apikey, string term)
    {
         ApiResponse<AirportAutocompleteResponse> response = AirportAutocompleteWithHttpInfo(apikey, term);
         return response.Data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Airport Autocomplete API provides a simple means to find an IATA location code for flight search based on a city or airport name. The API is fully JQuery-Autocomplete compatible to enable you to quickly build a drop-down list for your users to find the right airport easily. Given the start of any word in an airport&#39;s official name, a city name, or the start of an IATA code, this API provides the full name and IATA location code of the city or airport, for use in flight searches. Only major cities and civilian airports with several commercial flights per week are included by default. The response provides up to 20 possible matches, sorted by importance, in a &lt;a href=\&quot;http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/\&quot;&gt;JQuery UI Autocomplete&lt;/a&gt; compatible format. &lt;a href=\&quot;https://github.com/amadeus-travel-innovation-sandbox/sandbox-content/blob/master/airport-autocomplete-template.html\&quot;&gt;This sample implementation&lt;/a&gt; using JQuery UI may help. This API uses data from the OpenTravelData project, see https://github.com/opentraveldata/opentraveldata/blob/master/opentraveldata/optd_por_public.csv.\n\nThe value returned is the IATA location code. The label returned is always in UTF-8 format, with the airport official name (which is often in the native language), in the format of English City Name (if not already included in the airport name).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="apikey">API Key provided for your account, to identify you for API access</param> 
    /// <param name="term">Search term that should represent some part of a city or airport name.</param> 
    /// <returns>ApiResponse of AirportAutocompleteResponse</returns>
    public ApiResponse< AirportAutocompleteResponse > AirportAutocompleteWithHttpInfo (string apikey, string term)
    {

        // verify the required parameter 'apikey' is set
        if (apikey == null)
            throw new ApiException(400, "Missing required parameter 'apikey' when calling DefaultApi->AirportAutocomplete");

        // verify the required parameter 'term' is set
        if (term == null)
            throw new ApiException(400, "Missing required parameter 'term' when calling DefaultApi->AirportAutocomplete");


        var path_ = "/airports/autocomplete";

        var pathParams = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        var queryParams = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        var headerParams = new Dictionary<String, String>(Configuration.DefaultHeader);
        var formParams = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        var fileParams = new Dictionary<String, FileParameter>();
        Object postBody = null;

        // to determine the Content-Type header
        String[] httpContentTypes = new String[] {

        };
        String httpContentType = Configuration.ApiClient.SelectHeaderContentType(httpContentTypes);

        // to determine the Accept header
        String[] httpHeaderAccepts = new String[] {
            "application/json"
        };
        String httpHeaderAccept = Configuration.ApiClient.SelectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
        if (httpHeaderAccept != null)
            headerParams.Add("Accept", httpHeaderAccept);

        // set "format" to json by default
        // e.g. /pet/{petId}.{format} becomes /pet/{petId}.json
        pathParams.Add("format", "json");

        if (apikey != null) queryParams.Add("apikey", Configuration.ApiClient.ParameterToString(apikey)); // query parameter
        if (term != null) queryParams.Add("term", Configuration.ApiClient.ParameterToString(term)); // query parameter







        // make the HTTP request
        IRestResponse response = (IRestResponse) Configuration.ApiClient.CallApi(path_, 
            Method.GET, queryParams, postBody, headerParams, formParams, fileParams,
            pathParams, httpContentType);

        int statusCode = (int) response.StatusCode;

        if (statusCode >= 400)
            throw new ApiException (statusCode, "Error calling AirportAutocomplete: " + response.Content, response.Content);
        else if (statusCode == 0)
            throw new ApiException (statusCode, "Error calling AirportAutocomplete: " + response.ErrorMessage, response.ErrorMessage);

        return new ApiResponse<AirportAutocompleteResponse>(statusCode,
            response.Headers.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value.ToString()),
            (AirportAutocompleteResponse) Configuration.ApiClient.Deserialize(response, typeof(AirportAutocompleteResponse)));

    }
```

What i want to do its to retrieve the information from the response so i can use it later this its what ive tried till now:

```
        string apiKey = "MyApiKey";  //Not shown for obvious reasons
        DefaultApi Amadeus = new DefaultApi("https://api.sandbox.amadeus.com/v1.2");    


        AirportAutocompleteResponse response = Amadeus.AirportAutocomplete(apiKey, "adolfo suarez");                   
        textBox3.Text = response.ToString(); 




        /**********************TRIED*************************/

        /*****USING A LIST*****/
        /*
        List<AirportAutocompleteResponse> response = Amadeus.AirportAutocomplete(apiKey, "adolfo suarez");    
        textBox3.Text = response.ToString();
        */ //Does not compile since the response its not a list



        /*****AS ARRAY*****/
        //AirportAutocompleteResponse[] response = Amadeus.AirportAutocomplete(apiKey, "adolfo suarez");   
        //textBox3.Text = response.ToString(); //Doesnt work neither



        /*****AS STRING*****/

        /*
        string response = Amadeus.AirportAutocomplete(apiKey, "adolfo suarez").ToString();    
        textBox3.Text = response.ToString();
        */ //DOESNT WORK
```

The exception im getting its this:

An unhandled exception of type 'IO.Swagger.Client.ApiException' occurred in IO.Swagger.dll
            Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1, 2, 3]) into type 'IO.Swagger.Model.AirportAutocompleteResponse' because the type requires a JSON object(e.g. { "name":"value"})
            to deserialize correctly.
            To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. { "name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g.ICollection, IList) like List
            that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Since AirportAutocomplete its a class and the response seems to be a list or array of AirportAutocomplete class I get the exception mention before, ive tried using a list to get the response and arrays as show above but nothing works. Ive seems some people having this problem before and they solve it by

```
Deserialize<AiportAutocomplete>
```

as

```
Deserialize<List<AiportAutocomplete>>
```

But since im usign the APIs class i cant change that.
 ¿Its there a way to get this fix without having to do my own deserialiser?

Sorry for the extension but i want to include all the information that could help.

Comment: It sounds like the API class is out-of-date then, if it doesn't work with the real API out-of-the-box. I suggest you file a bug with Amadeus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for highlighting this issue Obito, I was able to reproduce it. As Rup mentioned above, this is indeed a bug in [the Swagger Specification that is used to build our client library](https://github.com/amadeus-travel-innovation-sandbox/sandbox-content/blob/master/swagger.yml).

I've fixed the bug and verified that it's working now for me. 
If it's still not working for you, please let us know, otherwise feel free to mark this answer as correct ;)