# Get new and existing items between lists

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

First we pull in new alerts and deserialize them. Now I only care about 2 properties that need to be compared: CommandID and AlertID, all others can be ignored so I create a new object which I assumed would have been easier to compare the results. All other properties become null.

```
List<AlertModel> alerts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AlertModel>>(json)
.Select(x => new AlertModel() { CommandID = x.CommandID, AlertID = x.AlertID }).ToList();
```

Now I want to find new alerts that don't already exist

```
List<AlertModel> newAlerts = alerts.Except(currentAlerts).ToList();
```

Next we pull what alerts already exist.

```
List<AlertModel> existingAlerts = currentAlerts.Intersect(alerts).ToList();
```

Now we store new and existing alerts.

```
currentAlerts.Clear();
currentAlerts.AddRange(newAlerts);
currentAlerts.AddRange(existingAlerts);
```

1st run `alerts` contains 1 item `newAlerts` contains 1 item and `existingAlerts` contains 0 as they should.

2nd run through isn't what I was expecting.

`alerts` contains 1 as it should.

`newAlerts` contains 1 and this should be 0. currentAlerts contains the exact same CommandID and AlertID as in `alerts`

`existingAlerts` contains 0 and this should be 1 since the same CommandID and AlertID exists in `currentAlerts` and `alerts`.

Not sure what i'm missing here and maybe there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Did you implement correctly `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in your `AlertModel` class?

Comment: I have not can you provide an example or point me to a post about it.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182358.aspx) is a place to start. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx) too. Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10454519/6400526)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
List<AlertModel> newAlerts = alerts.Except(currentAlerts).ToList();
```

Whit this:

```
List<AlertModel> newAlerts = alerts.Where(x => !currentAlerts.Any(y => y.CommandID == x.CommandID && y.AlertID == x.AlertID)).ToList();
```

The issue is that your `alerts` list contains new elements (`new AlertModel() { CommandID = x.CommandID, AlertID = x.AlertID }`). This is a reference problem.

```
Animal a = new Animal { Color = "Red" };
Animal b = new Animal { Color = "Red" };
a == b; // This returns false
```

Alternatively you can override `Equals` method in you class. To do this in your class:

```
public class AlertModel {
    // Some things

    public override bool Equals(object model) {
        return model != null && CommandID == model.CommandId && AlertID == model.AlertID;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may should consider to override GetHashCode() as well.

Comment: At the moment I never explore `GetHashCode()` method...so I will take a look for it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Override Equals and GetHashCode in your AlertModel class. Return a constant value in GetHashCode() (e.g. -1) if you want to force to call your Equals method.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var that = obj as AlertModel;

    return that != null && that.AlertId == this.AlertId && that.CommandId == this.CommandId; 
}

public override int GetHashCode()
    {           
        int hash = 13;
        return (this.AlertId.GetHashCode() * this.CommandID.GetHashCode()) ^ hash;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var uniqueAlerts = alerts.Where(a=> !currentAlerts.Any(c=> c.CommandID == a.CommandID && c.AlertID== a.AlertID));
```