# check for duplicates in object using all values minus a few

Tags: c#, duplicates

I'm trying to save a new object into my db and want to check if it's already in the db before saving.

And I want to check for duplicates by seeing if certain values in the objects are the same.

I have a

```
class Person 
{
  public string name
  public int age
  public string address
  public int zipCode
...
...
  public string createdBy
  public DateTime createdDate
}
```

i don't care if the createdBy and CreatedDate are the same or not, but i care about all the other values.

Instead of doing a check like this:

```
if (person1.name == person2.name && person1.age == person2.age &&
    person1.address == person2.address && person1.zipCode == person2.zipCode 
    ....... )
{
  //it's a duplicate
}
```

I am wondering if there's something like:

```
if (person1 == person2 [ignore createdBy && createdDate] )
{
  //it's a duplicate
}
```

EDIT: I have added more properties as an example because my object has about 15 properties total and I only want to compare on 13 properties instead of all 15. I know that manually checking every single property is an option but I am wondering if there is a way to compare the object minus 2 or 3 properties since that would be easier than comparing on 13 properties.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36125258/845655 In the `foreach` loop which iterates thru the properties you could check the property name and skip the comparison if the name is createdBy or createdDate

Comment: You might want to rethink storing `Age` especially if it bears on duplicates.  An age of 20 for example takes in 365 different DOBs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to compare two complex objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454519/best-way-to-compare-two-complex-objects)

Comment: You may want to utilize a library that provides easily created comparers in code: for example, https://github.com/StephenCleary/Comparers (disclaimer: I have no connection to the author. I just like this library).

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov That is interesting, but I don't see how it helps with not manually listing all properties. And updating when new properties are added. A nice extension to that library would be autogeneration of comparers, which would be an answer to this question.

Comment: @NetMage there are runtime comparers in the library. They do what the OP wants if it is ok to extract the list of all properties&#39; names through reflection once (and remove the ignored properties from the resulting list): https://github.com/StephenCleary/Comparers/blob/master/doc/run-time-comparers.md
I didn't use this feature though, so I can't comment on it.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov That's what I meant - an add-on that automates that process for any type using the library as a basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own method to do this.

```
    public bool IsDuplicatePerson(Person person1, Person person2)
    {
        if (person1.name == person2.name && person1.age == person2.age) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

And then call it by:

```
if(!IsDuplicatePerson(person1,person2))
{
     //do work
}
```

Comment: The original post explicitly says they don't want to list each property in a test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could help you, but here's a solution:

```
class Person{
    public string name;
    public float age;

    public string createdBy;

    public string GetValue(){
        return (name + " " + age.ToString());
    }
}

static void Main(){
    Person p1 = new Person();
    p1.age = 0; 
    p1.name = "hello";
    p1.createdBy = "no-one";
    Person p2 = new Person();
    p2.age = 0;
    p2.name = "hello";
    p2.createdBy = "me";
    if (p1.GetValue() == p2.GetValue())
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
```

Comment: Awfully wasteful solution it is... Please don't convert objects to strings for comparison purposes which creates a lot of unnecessary strings in addition to being incorrect for types that don't have a way to serialize value to be roundtrip-able (like floats may lose precision on converting to string)

Comment: Well first of all: I don't see any float in his values, second of all is a good way to debug for searching for errors, and third of all he already knew how to do it without these things so I just thought for another way.