# Why are Blazor lifecycle methods getting executed twice?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

So with a release of asp.net core 3.0 and blazor 1.0 I started doing some actual work with blazor. When splitting Blazor component code into code behind I am using the following

```
public class LogoutModel : BlazorComponent
{
}
```

Unfortunately `BlazorComponent` does not exist anymore, so I move to `ComponentBase`. Not sure when did this change took place..

Now the rest of my code looks like this

```
public class LogoutModel : ComponentBase
{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
    }
}
```

What i notice is that life cycle methods are executed in the following order

1. `OnInitializedAsync()`
2. `OnParametersSetAsync()`
3. `OnInitializedAsync()`
4. `OnParametersSetAsync()`

I am not really sure why is each method executed twice.

This is what my Blazor file looks like

```
@page  "/account/logout"
@inherits LogoutModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    Logout page
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which hosting model are you using?

Comment: I am usimng blazor Server

Answer (score 140, accepted):

## TL;DR

This is because of the prerendering mechanism that initializes the component as a part of the host page `_Host.cshtml`, so that the first http request would result in a host page that comes not only as a script loader of the blazor application, but also with a statically rendered view. Therefore the user could see the initial view without having to wait for roughly the following steps:

- A WebSocket connection is established by SignalR.
- The first bunch of render instructions are received from the server.
- The render instructions are applied to the view.

This would not only shorten the responding delay before the user see the initial view, but also benefit [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization#Getting_indexed). The prerendered view would be replaced by the real blazor component after the blazor application normally starts.

The prerendering feature is enabled by default within the new project template, so you have to choose one of the followings:

- Correctly handle the case that that component is prerendered (probably by checking whether the `IJSRuntime` is able to be resolved from the dependency injection).
- Disable the prerendering feature by modifying the `_Host.cshtml`, replacing

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

with

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
```

For legacy versions, replace

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

with

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.Server))
```

---

## The Original Answer

I did a test with a fresh new `blazorserver` project, logging when lifecycle methods are called, and got this output:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\Alsein\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: D:\repos\HelloWorld
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '/_Host'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {page = "/_Host"}. Executing page /_Host
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker[103]
      Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker[104]
      Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
crit: HelloWorld.MyBase[0]
      OnInitializedAsync
crit: HelloWorld.MyBase[0]
      OnParameterSetAsync
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker[4]
      Executed page /_Host in 122.3724ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint '/_Host'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 216.7341ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/css/site.css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/_framework/blazor.server.js
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/css/site.css'. Physical path: 'D:\repos\HelloWorld\wwwroot\css\site.css'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/_framework/blazor.server.js'. Physical path: 'N/A'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 44.733000000000004ms 200 text/css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css'. Physical path: 'D:\repos\HelloWorld\wwwroot\css\bootstrap\bootstrap.min.css'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 55.3613ms 200 text/css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 55.569900000000004ms 200 application/javascript
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/css/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css'. Physical path: 'D:\repos\HelloWorld\wwwroot\css\open-iconic\font\css\open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 4.5189ms 200 text/css
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:5001/_blazor/negotiate text/plain;charset=UTF-8 0
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:5001/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
      Sending file. Request path: '/css/open-iconic/font/fonts/open-iconic.woff'. Physical path: 'D:\repos\HelloWorld\wwwroot\css\open-iconic\font\fonts\open-iconic.woff'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 4.3562ms 200 application/font-woff
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '/_blazor/negotiate'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint '/_blazor/negotiate'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 24.7409ms 200 application/json
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:5001/_blazor?id=7oyJvbydrUy9tqlsH_DHzQ
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint '/_blazor'
crit: HelloWorld.MyBase[0]
      OnInitializedAsync
crit: HelloWorld.MyBase[0]
      OnParameterSetAsync
```

From the result we can see that, the component is loaded twice.

- The first time it was loaded as a simple Mvc component directly when the page is requested and handled by `/_Host` which must be specified with the following code in `_Host.cshtml`, which calls the lifecycle methods for the first time:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

- Then resources are loaded including `blazor.server.js`.
- Then the blazor app starts rendering.
- Then the component is loaded as a blazor component, where the lifecycle methods are called for the second time.

Try replacing `RenderMode.ServerPrerendered` with `RenderMode.Server`, then it behaves as expected, which is that the lifecycle methods are only called for once (when the blazor app starts).

Conclusion:
The default `RenderMode` is `ServerPrerendered` which must mean that Mvc could render the components as static contents in order to display the page contents before the blazor app is downloaded and starts, then when the blazor app starts, it takes over the page content. This must be a workaround for user experience that the browser user could wait less time for seeing the contents.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this, that helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks, here's the [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-model-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: If this were Nuxt.js, this would be similar to hybrid mode, where some part of the component or page can be controllably pre-rendered at the server, to speed things up, or use some service that is only available server-side (or should only be). There must be a way to check where the component is rendered, in the lifecycle method, I think I saw it somewhere but I don't remember it now. You could then simply do an if check and proceed accordingly.

Comment: if i can add something, this is what you have to change exactly in the _Host.cshtml file on the <app> element  : `render-mode="ServerPrerendered"` to `render-mode="Server"` --- [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/233675/blazor-oninitializedasync.html)

Comment: @KhalidAb The answer was written before the first GA version of blazor was released. The answer is updated.

Comment: @Alsein Then what is the benefit of these events if we can't use them precisely? As they will execute twice. I want to perform an action when first-time OnAfterRender is executed, but I can't do it. It's executing twice.

Comment: @CodeRider You could try resolving `IJsRuntime` from the `IServiceProvider` before executing your once-only logic, and if it fails with `null`, it means that the lifecycle method is executed within the prerendering context, and simply skip the once-only logic.

Comment: It seems this is still happening regardless of rendering mode used.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you. I found that the default template for index has two places where it needs to be changed. One for the HeadOutlet and one for App. I accidentally missed the App and still had the problem.
  <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
  <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

Answer (score 6):

You can use this method and you will have only once

```
protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            //do something
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Comment: But that firstRender param only exists in this particular event

Answer (score 5):

I solved my problem like this

Put this line at top of your page to prevent pre-rendering for dynamic parts

```
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender:false))
```

For other case if you are using a component in a Razor Or MVC use like this

```
<component type="typeof(UsersComponent)" render-mode="Server" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue with a holding page for a site where I had a little css animation which looked great in development, but when I put it live it ran twice. Changing the RenderMode to Server certainly fixes the issue, but it appears notably slower.

Funny because I would never have picked this up until I did this, for the final site I'll be switching back to ServerPrerendered

Comment: I switched to "Server' but still calls twice.   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {  await GetData() }    ???

Comment: @Jon - see my answer below - it fixes your issue

Answer (score 1):

Being tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21348

Meanwhile:

(Blazor WASM) - change from

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    await ReloadServerData();
}
```

to parameter setter:

```
[Parameter]
public string Foo
{
    get => _foo;
    set
    {
        // if you put a breakpoint here, you will realize, that this setter
        // gets called multiple times, but only once actually changes value
        if (_foo == value)
            return;

        _foo = value;

        ReloadServerData();
    }
}
```

being totally aware, that when ReloadServerData() fails, the property also fails to set value.

Comment: What if my parameter is of complex type? ex. of type Class

Comment: It's up to you and I would say it depends on specific case to decide if the object changes - check e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454519/best-way-to-compare-two-complex-objects

Comment: Or - if you need to detect change of specific property of some complex object, use custom event and then subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can call some methods or run some JS codes using the IJSRuntime one time only to do that  you can check the property IsFirtRender to execute some methods only once but it wont work for all the method sometimes it wont if the method is used before the render

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
For me it was that `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` was written twice on `_Host.cshtml`