# blazor server query string: how to get data only one time

Tags: blazor, query-string, .net-5, blazor-server-side, prerender

On blazor page we need to get data from query string.

We use `OnInitialized` event to read data:

[Working with Query Strings in Blazor](https://chrissainty.com/working-with-query-strings-in-blazor/)

for example:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var uri = NavManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavManager.Uri);
        if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("initialCount", out var _initialCount))
        {
            currentCount = Convert.ToInt32(_initialCount);
        }
    }
```

But we use prerendering:

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
```

and this code [executes two time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075628/why-are-blazor-lifecycle-methods-getting-executed-twice).

It's a problem, because we need to reach database with these parameters, but we don't want to do it twice.

Disable prerendering is not an option.

Tried to move code to other events, for example to `OnParametersSet`, but it executes twice too.

Maybe we can check it event executes first or second time and use this condition?

Or some other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a safe way to do this in .Net5 - you've tagged your Question with .Net5.

.Net6 adds `persist-prerendered-state`, which I think will solve your problem.  Here's a link to the MS-Docs page that explains how to use it:

[MS-Docs - Persist prerendered state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#persist-prerendered-state)