# Control in a List does not equate to the original control

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

So I have a list(panelList) that I created and I inserted 10 Panel controls (which are already created on the aspx design page).. However, when I try and check if panelList[0] is the same panel as Panel1(which is the first panel I added in panelList), I get returned FALSE... any idea why? Here is my code

---

```
 static List<Panel> panelList = new List<Panel>();
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (!IsPostBack) 
        {
            panelList.Add(Panel1);
            panelList.Add(Panel2);
            panelList.Add(Panel3);
            panelList.Add(Panel4);
            panelList.Add(Panel5);
            panelList.Add(Panel6);
            panelList.Add(Panel7);
            panelList.Add(Panel8);
            panelList.Add(Panel9);
            panelList.Add(Panel10);
         } 
  }  

   protected void AddQuestionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {    
       Debug.WriteLine(panelList[0].Equals(Panel1));
      // here i get returned false in the debug output
      }
```

---

Comment: Anything you did with Panel1 inbetween adding to the list and checking if it equals?

Comment: `Panel1` is got from aspx layout: it means after post back  (clicking AddQuestionButton) control is restored from form  data and it is not the same objects as was added to static list. `Equals` behavior might be implemented with different way for not the same object reference.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer nope, i only went through a loop and made all the panels invisible..

Comment: is there anyway i can make the equals comparison turn to true @OlegBondarenko

Comment: @SandroRamirez you could compare `Id` property  they are unique for each aspx controls.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider `How to compare 2 object in c#`, 
There are some ways to achieve this

1. Implement [IEquatable`<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)
2. Serialize both objects then compare them as string result

BTW, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454519/best-way-to-compare-two-complex-objects) link is helpful for you.