# How to check if a place in array is the same object as other object?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have the following code:

```cs
public static bool contains(Team [] ts, Team t)
{
    for(int i=0; i<ts.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ts[i]== t)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But somehow it always returns false. When I use `Equals` it throws  `NullReferenceException` and I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Have you run it in the debugger? Are you certain that `t` is already in the array?

Comment: It's doing reference comparison. If you have two different objects that represent the same Team, you need to code a different comparison.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few points in your question wich are worth discussing.

In order to compare `ts[i]` and `t` you are using the equality operator `==`. By default, this operator performs a reference equality check between the two operands, put in other words this is equivalent to calling `object.ReferenceEquals(ts[i], t)`. This means that the two operands are considered equal if and only if they are two references to the **same** memory location.

If this is not the equality semantic that you intend for the class `Team`, you need to override both the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods and both the operators `==` and `!=`. After that, your code will automatically use the equality semantic that you have defined in your overrides. Start from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netcore-3.1) if you need more details on this.

The second important point is the one related with the `NullReferenceException`. If you call `t[i].Equals(t)` and `t[i]` is a `null` reference then you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. So you have the following choices:

- checks whether `t[i]` is a `null` reference before calling `Equals`
- use the equality operator instead
- use the static method `object.Equals` instead

Last but not the least, as pointed out in other answers what you are trying to do [is already implemented in .NET framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_) and you should use the already existing `Contains` extension method.

Notice that when using the already existing [Contains extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_) you still need to override the equality members of the `Team` class, as explained above.

As an alternative, you can decide to use [this overload of the Contains extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) which allows you to specify the desired equality semantic at the call site, by means of a custom equality comparer (an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<Match>` in your case). This can be useful if, for any reason, defining several different equality semantics for the `Team` class (based on the context) makes sense. If you always want to compare `Match` instances using the **same** equality semantic, stick with the first choice of overriding the equality members of the class (as explained above) and use [the overload of Contains having one parameter only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_).

Answer (score 0):

It is usually a good way to learn to check how .net framework implemented similiar behaviour in their code.

From [.Net Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,03bc07d71083c0b8):

> ```
>     // Contains returns true if the specified element is in the ArrayList.
>     // It does a linear, O(n) search.  Equality is determined by calling
>     // item.Equals().
>     //
>     public virtual bool Contains(Object item) {
>         if (item==null) {
>             for(int i=0; i<_size; i++)
>                 if (_items[i]==null)
>                     return true;
>             return false;
>         }
>         else {
>             for(int i=0; i<_size; i++)
>                 if ( (_items[i] != null) && (_items[i].Equals(item)) )
>                     return true;
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create an interface with an Equals method and then the class implement that interface.

With your example:

```
public interface IEqualable<T>
{
    public bool Equal(T t);
}

public class Team : IEqualable<Team>
{
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public bool Equal(Team t2)
    {
        if(t2 is null) return false; 
        if (this.TeamName == t2.TeamName)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Team[3] { new Team() { TeamName = "qwe" }, new Team() { TeamName = "asd" }, new Team() { TeamName = "qq" } };
        Console.WriteLine(contains(p, new Team { TeamName = "qq" }));
    }

    public static bool contains(Team[] ts, Team t)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (ts[i].Equal(t))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454519/best-way-to-compare-two-complex-objects)