# Get list of matching objects from 3 different lists

Tags: c#, .net, list, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I'm exercising on one task. Basically i got 3 different lists in C# code side. Class employee is containing the skills list. And also have list of employees as well.

for example :

```
class Employee
{
   List<Skills> Skills;
}

class Skills
{
   int Id;
   int Name;
}

class Where_Im_Working_Currently
{
   List<Employee> employees ;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get list of common skills from every individual.  suppose we have 3 employees and all 3 employees have JAVA skill in common such that { id = x , name = JAVA }.

so all 3 employees have skills similar with id and name needs to be fetched out.

**NOTE : I'm trying to get all matching skills and not just subset of skills**

```
for e.g. 
    Case 1: Perfect match. (Get List having a, b, c)
         list 1 =>  a, b, c
         list 2 =>  a, b, c
         list 3 =>  a, b, c

    Case 1: No match. (Get Null list)
         list 1 =>  a, b, c
         list 2 =>  a, b,
         list 3 =>  b, c
```

following is the query i have come up with :

```
var skills= employees.Select(x => x.Skills.Select(p => p.Id== x.Skill[0].Id && p.Name == x.Skill[0].Name));
```

but this will give IEnumerable that's where its getting wrong and im unable to form LINQ.

Any pointers or help are welcomed.

Comment: I don't understand why you put this comparison in there. Could you elaborate on it? from your text: "get list of common skills from every individual" you don't really want to filter. You want all skills. Are you trying to remove duplicates?

Comment: @MongZhu my bad. edited the question header. yes i need all the skills. And not dealing with duplicates. all common skill objects need to taken out that's the only intention.

Comment: ok do you want the duplicates removed if some employees have the same skills? otherwise you could simply remove the comparison inside the inner select and take only `p`

Comment: @MongZhu The comparison is to ensure all objects have same properties. and i want those all objects having similar properties in one separate list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the most optimized way of doing this, but here's a solution that outputs the skills that are common for all employees.

The key is to use `SelectMany` to get to the child lists.

```
public class Employee
{
    public List<Skills> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skills
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void GetSomeSkills()
{
    var employees = new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee { Skills = new List<Skills> { new Skills { Id = 1, Name = "Java" }, new Skills { Id = 2, Name = "C#" } } },
        new Employee { Skills = new List<Skills> { new Skills { Id = 1, Name = "Java" }, new Skills { Id = 3, Name = "Cooking" } } },
        new Employee { Skills = new List<Skills> { new Skills { Id = 1, Name = "Java" } } },
        //new Employee { Skills = new List<Skills> { new Skills { Id = 4, Name = "C++" } } }
    };

    var allSkills = employees.SelectMany(x => x.Skills).ToList();
    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", allSkills.Select(x => x.Name)));
    // Output: Java, C#, Java, Cooking, Java

    var commonSkills = employees.SelectMany(e =>
        e.Skills.Where(s => employees.All(e2 => e2.Skills.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(s.Id)))).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", commonSkills.Select(x => x.Name)));
    // Output: Java, Java, Java
}
```

If you uncomment the last Employee you would have a zero result, as there would no longer be a skill that is common for all employees.

Also you probably want to get distinct result, but it sounds like you already know how to do that.

**Edit after original question was modified:**

The below outputs only the skills that everyone has, if you uncomment the last Employee you would have null as result.

```
[Test]
public void GetSomeSkills()
{
    var employees = new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee { Skills = new List<Skills> { new Skills { Id = 1, Name = "Java" }, new Skills { Id = 2, Name = "C#" } } },
        new Employee { Skills = new List<Skills> { new Skills { Id = 1, Name = "Java" }, new Skills { Id = 2, Name = "C#" } } },
        // new Employee { Skills = new List<Skills> { new Skills { Id = 1, Name = "Java" } } },
    };

    bool HasSameSkills(Employee first, Employee second)
    {
        var firstIds = first.Skills.Select(x => x.Id).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        var secondIds = second.Skills.Select(x => x.Id).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
        return firstIds.SequenceEqual(secondIds);
    }

    var commonSkills = employees.FirstOrDefault(x => employees.All(y => HasSameSkills(x, y)))?.Skills;

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", (commonSkills ?? new List<Skills>()).Select(x => x.Name)));
    // Output: Java, C#
}
```

Comment: man this is fantastic. But added one more restriction on output. All skills should match and not subset. can this be possible ?

Comment: Thanks man for showing me the new way to crush such problems. Absolutely thrilled to see the solution. Once again big thanks. If you are a youtuber then please leave YouTube channel link so that i can learn from you.