# Assert.Contains doesn't find the object in a list

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I'm new to unit testing, and I wanted to test a method that gets a string array that contains some names like "John,Doe" and then it splits the name by the "," and populates a list of `PersonModel` with those names, so I expect that there is a PersonModel with first name John, and last name Doe, in the returned list, but the `Assert.Contains` method keeps throwing this error:

> Assert.Contains() Failure
>
> Not found: PersonModel { FirstName = "John", FullName = "John Doe",
> LastName = "Doe" }
>
> In value:  List [PersonModel {
> FirstName = "John", FullName = "John Doe", LastName = "Doe" },
> PersonModel { FirstName = "Jane", FullName = "Jane Doe", LastName =
> "Doe" }]

This is the method for converting names to people list in the `DataAccess` class:

```
public static List<PersonModel> ConvertCsvNamesToPeopleList(string[] csvContent)
{
    List<PersonModel> output = new List<PersonModel>();

    foreach (string line in csvContent)
    {
        string[] data = line.Split(',');
        output.Add(new PersonModel { FirstName = data[0], LastName = data[1] });
    }

    return output;
}
```

And this is the test:

```
[Fact]
public void ConvertCsvNamesToPeopleList_ValidCsvContent_ShouldWork()
{
    string[] csvContent = { "John,Doe", "Jane,Doe" };

    var expectedPerson = new PersonModel { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
    var expectedPerson2 = new PersonModel { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" };
    var actual = DataAccess.ConvertCsvNamesToPeopleList(csvContent);

    Assert.Contains(expectedPerson, actual);
    Assert.Contains(expectedPerson2, actual);
}
```

The person model:

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName => $"{ FirstName } { LastName }";
}
```

Comment: Does `PersonModel` override `Equals`?

Comment: @Mureinik No it doesn't

Comment: And `PersonModel` is a `class`, right? Not a `record` or a `struct`? What you're running into is [reference vs value equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/equality-comparisons#:~:text=Reference%20equality%20means%20that%20two,shown%20in%20the%20following%20example.&text=In%20this%20code%2C%20two%20objects,refer%20to%20the%20same%20object.). The objects have the same *value*, but are not the same object in memory and so are not equal.

Comment: @DM Yeah it's a class

Comment: Take a look at [Best way to compare two complex objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454519/best-way-to-compare-two-complex-objects). There are multiple ways to compare class instances by value. As @Mureinik points out, the easiest would be to [override `Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2022).

Comment: @DM Oh, I didn't know anything about that, thanks

Comment: No worries! Worth noting that you get this functionality for free if you're using instances of a [`record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) (available in C# 9.0 or newer): [Try it out on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uxDxs2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Contains` relies on finding two objects that are equal, so you should override its `Equals` method. For good measures, you should override its `GetHashCode` method too, so you can use it as a key of a dictionary if you ever need to:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is PersonModel model &&
           FirstName == model.FirstName &&
           LastName == model.LastName;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return HashCode.Combine(FirstName, LastName);
}
```

Comment: To override the `GetHashCode`, I couldn't find `HashCode` anywhere, I tried `System.HashCode` but it's not there anymore, how should I use it?

Comment: @Genesys if you don't have `HashCode` available, there are a few ways you can implement `GetHashCode` yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/q/263400/2422776