# C# ObservableCollection.IndexOf(...) returns -1

Tags: c#, collections

I wrote this code to check a Collection to find objects with the same value, but it returns the index -1 and causes an IndexOutOfRangeException. Can anyone help find my mistake?

```
List<MyFileInfo> selectedItemsList = dataInbox.SelectedItems.Cast<MyFileInfo>().ToList();
foreach (MyFileInfo file in selectedItemsList)
{
    if (!file.AdditionalColumn.Equals(""))
    {
        inDB = new ZeichnungInDB(file.FileInfo.Name, file.AdditionalColumn, file.AdditionalColumn2, file.FileInfo.Extension,
        txtAenderungExtern.Text, file.AdditionalColumn3,
        int.Parse(txtProjectNumber.Text), txtTag.Text, bemerkung, anhangPfad, cmbDokumententyp.Text, false);
        if (zeichnungCollection.Count > 0)
        {
            if (zeichnungCollection[zeichnungCollection.IndexOf(inDB)].Zeichnungsnummer != inDB.Zeichnungsnummer &&
            zeichnungCollection[zeichnungCollection.IndexOf(inDB)].Extension != inDB.Extension)
            {
                zeichnungCollection.Add(inDB);
            }
            else
            {
                sameData = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            zeichnungCollection.Add(inDB);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On code formatting: Indent your entire block so that the outermost level has four spaces of indent, and you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of an object, you are then attempting to find the Index of that object where your collection actually holds reference to a different instance.

You can use `FindIndex` with `ToList` to pass in a predicate and find the index of the object where a condition is true.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx

Alternatively, you could use `FirstOrDefault` with some null checking if you'd prefer to keep it as an `ObservableCollection`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hm, I have no FindIndex Method.

Comment: `zeichnungCollection.ToList().FindIndex(Predicate)`

Comment: A bit inefficient, though. The precise type of `zeichnungCollection` isn't given; if you can make it a `List<T>` you'll avoid the allocation of a new list.

Comment: The title contains the type as an ObservableCollection, but I agree on the inefficiency piece of converting it to a type of `List<T>`

I updated my answer to also include `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: That's better, yes. (And I completely missed that the type was specified in the title...)

Answer (score 2):

Assume `MyFileInfo` looks like this:

```
public class MyFileInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now try to use it like this:

```
List<MyFileInfo> selectedItemsList = new List<MyFileInfo>
    {
        new MyFileInfo { Name = "One" },
        new MyFileInfo { Name = "Two" },
    };

MyFileInfo two = new MyFileInfo { Name = "Two" };
int index = selectedItemsList.IndexOf(two); // index == -1
```

`IndexOf` is looking for identical instance references, which it doesn't find, and so returns -1.

If you do this instead, though, the references are the same:

```
MyFileInfo two = new MyFileInfo { Name = "Two" };
List<MyFileInfo> selectedItemsList = new List<MyFileInfo>
    {
        new MyFileInfo { Name = "One" },
        two,
    };

int index = selectedItemsList.IndexOf(two); // index == 1
```

This is due to the default implementation of the `Equals` method, which just compares for reference equality. If you override `Equals` in `MyFileInfo`, you get to decide what `Equals` means. For example:

```
public class MyFileInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj?.GetType() == typeof(MyFileInfo))
        {
            return ((MyFileInfo)obj).Name == Name;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This will find any object with the same `Name`.

Using methods with predicates is another option, which allows you to define what `Equals` means on the fly, e.g.:

```
List<MyFileInfo> selectedItemsList = new List<MyFileInfo>
    {
        new MyFileInfo { Name = "One" },
        new MyFileInfo { Name = "Two" },
    };

MyFileInfo two = new MyFileInfo { Name = "Two" };
int index = selectedItemsList.FindIndex(info => info.Name == two.Name);
```

Which also finds items with the same `Name`.

**Note**: If you override `Equals` in any class that might be used as a dictionary (hash table) key, you should also override `GetHashCode`. [Here's a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363143/whats-the-best-strategy-for-equals-and-gethashcode). And there are considerations for implementing various other interfaces such as `IEquatable<T>`, especially for `struct`s (value objects), which I guess is out of scope for this question.

**Edit**: [Why it's important to override GetHashCode when overriding Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)

Comment: Hm, this solution looks interesting, too. Maybe I will check that out after the weekend, if I can make that work for my problem.