# Assert.Equal() Failure

Tags: c#, xunit

during unit testing have some problem using Assert.Equels(expected, actual).
I have the next message

Expected: MyClass { Id = 1, Name = "Vasia Vasiliew", Value = 10 }

Actual:   MyClass { Id = 1, Name = "Vasia Vasiliew", Value = 10 }

but the Assert.Equal() Failure

Assert.True(actual.equels(expected)) is failure too

How can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps the instances are not the same. Try Changing your `class` to `record` this will force it to compare properties

Comment: What does your `MyClass` look like? By default C# implements class equals by checking whether the references are equal, so you probably need to manually override the `bool Equal(Object other)` member

Comment: Note that the *override* is `bool Equals(object obj)`. You might *also* want to implement `IEquatable<MyClass>` with a signature of `bool Equals(MyClass other)`.

Comment: You need to define "equality" for your class - by default, classes use _instance_ equality. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363143) for an example

Comment: As the other comments say, Assert.Equals check the reference on classes. Either use a record, implement the equality function or use Fluent Assertions which actually traverses the object graph